# Short exact sequence with binary tetrahedral group does not split

Tags: group-theory

The following is a short exact sequence, where $T$ is the binary tetrahedral group (equivalently the Hurwitz units), and $Q$ is the quotient of $T$ by $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

$1 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow T \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 1$.

Wikipedia tells me that this doesn't split-- i.e. that there is no map $\phi: Q \rightarrow T$ which is the identity on $Q$ when composed with the map from $Q$ to $T$. Why is this true, preferably from as elementary a perspective as possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the extension split, then the image of $Q$ ($\cong A_4$) inside $T$ under a splitting homomorphism would be normal, as its index would be equal to $2$.  However, the only normal subgroups are the centre of order $2$ and the quaternion subgroup of index $3$.

One way to see that $T$ has no subgroup of index $2$ is to note that, if it did, then by the correspondence theorem, so too would $Q\cong A_4$.  But, $A_4$ has no subgroup of index $2$ (i.e., of order $6$).  This is often cited as a counter-example to the converse of Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: How do we know by looking at $T$ as the set of Hurwitz units that it has no index 2 subgroup?

Comment: Or rather, how can we deduce this without knowing that the only normal subgroups are the center and the quaternion subgroup?

Comment: @user151882.  I've added some more information to the answer to, I hope, clarify things.

Comment: Thanks! One further question-- what's a nice way to see that $Q$ is $A_4$?